# How to create the object of class LocalDate in Java? And why not use new keyword?

Tags: java

I am using this code to create the object of class **LocalDate** in Java.time package but it does not require the keyword **new**. Can anyone tell me how this exactly works.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
```

Comment: It's known as a "factory" method.  You pass it the properties you want it to use and it will create a new instance of the class for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class has a private constructor. So you cannot instantiate a new instance of the [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class using the new keyword. But the [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class implements a static function [of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-), which lets you specify the year, month, and day of the month, and the function returns the new constructed [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object.

Answer (score 2):

LocalDate provides a static method named `of` that allocates a new instance.

Any class can do this.

```
    class MyClass {
          :
       static MyClass makeOne(int someArg) {
           :
          MyClass thing = new MyClass();
           :
          return thing;
       }
        :
     }
```

`makeOne` might equally be named `of` if that makes sense.

So, you're right, 'new' is how instances get created, but that doesn't mean the 'new' call is written in **your** code.